# Error in connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I am using Java to connect **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2** and `sqljdbc4.jar`, but there is a problem with the initial connection. After running, 3 is displayed in the browser only.

This is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
public class Database { 
static Connection con = null;
public static int dbConnect() {
    int x = 3;
    try {
        // Establish the connection. 
        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setIntegratedSecurity(true);
        ds.setServerName("172.18.16.10");
        ds.setPortNumber(1433); 
        ds.setDatabaseName("my-database");
        ds.setUser("my-user");
        ds.setPassword("my-pass");
        con = ds.getConnection();
        x = 5;
        if (con != null) {
            x = 1;
        }else{
            x = 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }
    return x;   
}}
```

and this is the error I receive:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication.
>   ClientConnectionId:af711e9c-941f-4535-9ccb-b6ef31a42fdf

The older questions about my problem in SO were not helpful for me. I added `sqljdbc-auth.jar` into `/java/bin` and `path` also in `/java/lib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add sqljdbc.jar and import that :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
```

I define all need variable in Global ans Static :

```
private static SQLServerDataSource ds = null;
private static Connection con = null;
```

and define a method for connect:

```
    public static boolean getConnection() {
    try {
        System.out.println(ServerName);
        ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setServerName(ServerName);
        ds.setPortNumber(1433);
        ds.setDatabaseName(DatabaseName);
        ds.setUser(UserName);
        ds.setPassword(Password);
        con = ds.getConnection();
        if (con != null) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        return true;
    } // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Database {
    static Connection con = null

    public static int dbConnect() {
        int x = 3;
        try {
            // Establish the connection. 
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://172.18.16.10:1433;databaseName=my-database;user=my-user;password=my-pass;");

            x = 5;
            if (con != null) {
                x = 1;
            }else{
                x = 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
        }
        return x;   
    }
}
```

You will get a proper connection using the above code.

Morever, the driver Name ("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") and the connection url should always be read from a config file. Try taking the above two things out of your code into a config file.